# llvm: create double* type pointer which stores double type elements

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm working with llvm and C++ and trying to create a double type pointer which stores double type elements.
In the example below I'm trying to create a pointer which stores three elements:

```
Function *function = builder.GetInsertBlock()->getParent(); 
IRBuilder<> blockBB(&function->getEntryBlock(), function->getEntryBlock().begin());
AllocaInst* arrPtr = blockBB.CreateAlloca(Type::getDoublePtrTy(context), ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context), sizeof(double)*3), "arrayName"); //creates double* type pointer 

auto value = ConstantFP::get(context, APFloat(9.0));
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
 //.....don't know how to assign values to arrPtr

}
```

I will be grateful for the advices.

Comment: Why have you discarded std containers and pair?

Comment: You should also be aware that you're creating `sizeof(double) * 3` elements instead of 3 elements in the alloca array which is most likely not what you're intending to do. You want to pass `3` instead.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve is it a double array containing constants? Or are you putting the constant 9.0 into the first array element? You don't want `sizeof(double)*3` just 3 if it is an array of 3 doubles.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you need something like this.

```
auto value = ConstantFP::get(context, APFloat(9.0));
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    //.....don't know how to assign values to arrPtr
    //I assume this is what you want?
    //note we GEP here by index 0 then i as we have pointer to array of doubles not pointer to doubles
    vector<llvm::Value*> objidxs = { llvm::ConstantInt::get(blockBB.getInt32Ty(), 0), llvm::ConstantInt::get(blockBB.getInt32Ty(), i) };
    llvm::Value* nptr = blockBB.CreateGEP(arrPtr, llvm::ArrayRef(&*objidxs.begin(), &*objidxs.end()));
    blockBB.CreateStore(nptr, value);
}
```

First you index into the double array (making a new pointer `nptr`) then you store a value at the position you have indexed into the array.

NOTE: not tested or compiled

If you want a constant array of double that would be something different.

This also need to be:

```
//creates pointer to double[3] type
AllocaInst* arrPtr = blockBB.CreateAlloca(Type::getDoubleTy(context), ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(context), 3), "arrayName");
```

To create an array of 3 doubles, `arrPtr` is a pointer to that array.